# Expanded TCL interpreter in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have implemented many TCL extensions for a specific tool in the domain of formal methods (extensions are implemented in C but I do not want solution to rely on this fact). Thus, the users of my tool can use TCL for prototyping algorithms. Many of them are just linear list of commands (they are powerfull), e.g.:

```
my_read_file f
my_do_something a b c
my_do_something_else a b c
```

Now, I am interested in timing. It is possible to change the script to get:

```
puts [time [my_read_file f] 1] 
puts [time [my_do_something a b c] 1] 
puts [time [my_do_something_else a b c] 1]
```

Instead of this I want to define procedure xsource that executes a TCL script and get/write timing for all my commands. Some kind of a profiler. I wrote a naive implementation where the main idea is as follows:

```
 set f [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
 set inputLine ""
 while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
   set d [expr [string length $line] - 1]
   if { $d >= 0 } {
     if { [string index $line 0] != "#" } {
       if {[string index $line $d] == "\\"} {
         set inputLine "$inputLine [string trimright [string range $line 0 [expr $d - 1]]]"
       } else {
         set inputLine "$inputLine $line"
         set inputLine [string trimleft $inputLine]
         puts $inputLine
         puts [time {eval $inputLine} 1]
       }
       set inputLine ""
     }
   }
 }
```

It works for linear list of commands and even allows comments and commands over multiple lines. But it fails if the user uses if statements, loops, and definition of procedures. Can you propose a better approach? It must be pure TCL script with as few extensions as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing what you're asking for is to use [execution traces](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9). Here's a script that can do just that:

```
package require Tcl 8.5

# The machinery for tracking command execution times; prints the time taken
# upon termination of the command. More info is available too (e.g., did the
# command have an exception) but isn't printed here.
variable timerStack {}
proc timerEnter {cmd op} {
    variable timerStack
    lappend timerStack [clock microseconds]
}
proc timerLeave {cmd code result op} {
    variable timerStack
    set now [clock microseconds]
    set then [lindex $timerStack end]
    set timerStack [lrange $timerStack 0 end-1]
    # Remove this length check to print everything out; could be a lot!
    # Alternatively, modify the comparison to print more stack frames.
    if {[llength $timerStack] < 1} {
        puts "[expr {$now-$then}]: $cmd"
    }
}

# Add the magic!
trace add execution source enterstep timerEnter
trace add execution source leavestep timerLeave
# And invoke the magic, magically
source [set argv [lassign $argv argv0];set argv0]
# Alternatively, if you don't want argument rewriting, just do:
# source yourScript.tcl
```

Then you'd call it like this (assuming you've put it in a file called `timer.tcl`):

```
tclsh8.5 timer.tcl yourScript.tcl
```

Be aware that this script has a considerable amount of overhead, as it inhibits *many* optimization strategies that are normally used. That won't matter too much for uses where you're doing the real meat in your own C code, but when it's lots of loops in Tcl then you'll notice a lot.

Comment: This worked for me and it is very elegant. The only drawback here is that report cannot be limited to the subset of commands (if this would be important then the solution from GrAnd has to be considered).

Comment: @meolic: You could always apply a post-processing step. For example, dump all the log info to a file and then just grep for the interesting bits.

Comment: @DonalFellows about your last note of inhibiting optimization, is it at least safe in comparing results? i.e. if I have a script and refactored it into another one, will it be safe in comparing the timing between both or is it possible that the optimization reverses the result?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your commands which you want to measure. And name wrappers exactly as the original ones (renaming original procs before). After that, when instrumented command is executed it actually executes the wrapper, which executes the original procedure and measure the time of execution. The example below (Tcl 8.5).

```
proc instrument {procs} {
  set skip_procs {proc rename instrument puts time subst uplevel return}
  foreach p $procs {
    if {$p ni $skip_procs} {
      uplevel [subst -nocommands {
        rename $p __$p
        proc $p {args} {
          puts "$p: [time {set r [__$p {*}\$args]}]"
          return \$r
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

proc my_proc {a} {
  set r 1
  for {set i 1} {$i <= $a} {incr i} {
    set r [expr {$r * $i}]
  }
  return $r
}

proc my_another_proc {a b} {
  set r 0
  for {set i $a} {$i <= $b} {incr i} {
    incr r $i
  }
  return $r
}

instrument [info commands my_*]

puts "100 = [my_proc 100]"
puts "200 = [my_proc 100]"
puts "100 - 200 = [my_another_proc 100 200]"
```

Comment: Interesting idea and quite complex implementation (TCL geeks do indeed like it). I notice two problems. First, all commands have to be defined before calling `instrument` and if a new command is added afterwards, `instrument` must be called again. More critical is that I do not know how to undo this wraping. I want to be able to use it only sometimes and not all the time.

Comment: To `uninstrument` just do `rename __$p  $p`, where $p - is the name of command. To `instrument` procedures which are not defined yet, you can 'wrap' `proc` command which will instrument all procedures automatically upon their definition. It will not work for C++ procs (in this case you can wrap `load` command to catch this). :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the command "info complete". It can tell you if what you have accumulated so far looks complete from the point of view of most common Tcl syntax markers. It will deal with command input that might be spread across multiple physical lines.

Comment: Useful to improve the naive implementation. Still not a solution for the problem where I want timing for every single command in a loop.